# arraylist giving "cannot be resolved" and "cannot be resolved to a type" errors (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, selection-sort

I'm writing a Selection Sort program, and it's still unfinished, so there are a lot of errors, but the one I'm looking to fix first is the error that eclipse keeps giving me:

```
thelist cannot be resolved to a type
```

and again, in the rest of the program:

```
thelist cannot be resolved
```

my program looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SelectionSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    //populate list with number from 1 to N

    // Create an ArrayList containing Integer type elements
    ArrayList<Integer> thelist = new ArrayList();

    //while loop to accept a new value from random generator

    //call sort method
}

public static void sort(final thelist<Integer> list) {

    // declare an int variable to hold value of index at which the element
    // has the smallest value
        int smaller = 0;
        int b=0;

     // declare an int variable to hold the smallest value for each iteration
     // of the outer loop
        int smallerindex = 0;      

        for(int a=1;a<thelist.size();a++){
            /* find the index at which the element has smallest value */
            // initialize variables
            smaller = thelist.get(a-1);
            smallerindex = a-1;

            for(b=a;b<thelist.size();b++){
                if(thelist.get(b)<smaller){
                    // update smallest
                    smaller = thelist.get(b);
                    smallerindex = b;
                }
            }
         // do nothing if the curIndex has the smallest value
            //Swap the smallest element with the first element of unsorted subarray
            int temp = thelist.get(destIndex);
            thelist.set(destIndex, thelist.get(sourceIndex));
            thelist.set(sourceIndex, temp);

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: `thelist` is not a valid type. The signature of the sort method should be `sort(ArrayList<Integer> list)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your sort method your are giving thelist as the type of the parameter list:

`public static void sort(final thelist<Integer> list) {`

change it for:

`public static void sort(final ArrayList<Integer> list) {`

Then in the main method when you need to call the sort method, you call it like this:

```
//call sort method
sort(thelist);
```

and that's the way you will have your list "thelist" and use it in your method.

Comment: You also need to EITHER change `thelist` to `list` in the body of the method, OR change the parameter name to `thelist`.